# TDD with impossible exceptions

Tags: java, junit, exception, tdd

I have got a problem with TDD and impossible exceptions.

Let's say we have got a class named Foo (example):

```
Class Foo {
    public String getString(boolean shouldThrow) throws Exception {
        if(shouldThrow) throw new Exception();
        return "nonsense";
    }
}
```

Foo throws an exception only under certain circumstances (for simplicity i take a boolean here).

Now i want to create a class named Bar which reverses the string of Foo without throwing an exception.

Test:

```
class BarTest {
    public void testShouldReturnReversedStringOfBar() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        assertEquals("esnesnon", bar.getReversedString());
    }
}
```

I know that the boolean is false all the time. So the method getReversedString() will never throw an exception. But since it throws no exception, I can't write an assert which leads me to write the try/catch block inside of Bar.

So the Test will look like this:

```
class BarTest {
    public void testShouldReturnReversedStringOfBar() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        try {
            assertEquals("esnesnon", bar.getReversedString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ... will never happen
        }
    }
}
```

But that is bad, because the exception will never happen and I have to write the try/catch-block every time I use the getReversedString() method.
So I want the class like this:

```
class Bar {
    public String getReversedString() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        try {
            String s = foo.getString(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // will never happen...
        }
        // ... reverse string ...
        return reversedString;
    }
}
```

But since the exception will never happen, I can't write a test for that try/catch-block - so I can't write the try/catch-block inside of Bar because TDD says "only write code if the lights are red".

It is a doom loop...

I hope you got me!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the *test itself* throw the exception:

```
public void testShouldReturnReversedStringOfBar() 
    throws Exception
{
    Bar bar = new Bar();

    assertEquals("esnesnon", bar.getReversedString());
}
```

If an exception is thrown then the test will be marked as an error; which is "a failure but not as we know it, Jim" -- that fails anyway.

---

and by the way, throwing `Exception` is bad practice; when you catch `Exception` you also get to catch all `RuntimeException`s, that is, all unchecked exceptions as well. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks! But with your solution i have to add "throws Exception" to every method which uses the getReversedString()-Method. Since the exception will never be thrown, i think it's bad practise. I need a test which forces me to write the try/catch-block inside of Bar.

Comment: "Since the exception will never be thrown, i think it's bad practise" -- no it isn't. If the exception is thrown, your test fails and that's it. And, again, don't throw Exception. Throw a more specific type (preferrably one which does not extend `RuntimeException`).

Comment: I think you are right. Maybe it's the best solution. In my program it's an IOException by the way.

Comment: Is there a way to "rename exceptions" via tdd?
The thirdy-party library throws an IOException. But my class has nothing to do with I/O. So someone who is using my library will think "wtf? Why IOException?".

Comment: Still, if you use that library and use that method you don't have much of a choice, right? Note that if you implement/extend a method which throws, you can choose to throw a subclass of the exception; this is how `Closeable` vs `AutoCloseable` works (`AutoCloseable`'s `.close()` throws `Exception`, `Closeable`, which extends `AutoCloseable`, throws `IOException` in `.close()`)

Answer (score 0):

You could either add a throws declaration to the test method as fge already suggested, or you could consider re-designing your code by splitting your if into two separate methods (one that throws exception and one that doesn't)

```
class Foo {

    public String getStringWithException() throws Exception {
        // return data or throw exception if something goes wrong
    }

    public String getStringWithoutException() {
        // return data
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks, but that is not possible because it's a third-party library.

Answer (score 0):

The `TDD` is a way to help you verify your program can work correctly. Though the `Exception` will never occur. I think you can `throw Exception` in `junit` test method. Just like:

```
public void testShouldReturnReversedStringOfBar() throw Exception{
    ....
}
```